# Allowing div to expand or move past container

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have an issue (code is dynamic so difficult to print - I hope this is simple) whereby when a parent container div contains 3 div elements floated left, yet the if the 3rd div goes beyond the body of the page (i.e. the browser's width) it line breaks to go underneath.

I want it to float: left whatever, whether it goes past the 'end of the browser' or not. Is this possible?

Example code:-

```
<div id="container"><div id="divLeft"></div><div id="divCenter"></div><div id="divRight"></div></div>
```

Where all the divs left, center and right are float: left;

Yet #divLeft will break to go under divCenter if it's width goes outside the browser width.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: if the container has a fixed width, then this is the default behavior I think

Comment: Do any of these divs have any margin, padding, or border? If so, how much of each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to be sure is to set a fixed width to your `div` here.

[An example here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/bhfZq/)

```
#container{width:306px;display:block;border:1px solid black;overflow:auto;}
#divLeft, #divCenter,#divRight{float:left;border:1px solid red;width:100px;}
```

Don't forget the `overflow:auto` on your container if you want to apply a background or a border, else it won't be under your divs.

Comment: You're quite right, it does fix the issue. The reason I hadn't was the wrapped needed to expand to dynamic widths, but I've handed it to the builder with the set width each time I need it. So seems to work. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it seems the divs don't fit in container div, and the last one floats under them. this is how float works. you must arrange the widths of them.